# Why is the Kochsche Curve and programming so similiar?

Tags: logic, epistemology, aristotle, artificial-intelligence

I've question which I'm looking for longer time. The iteration process while a for loop > for statement in function_declaration: is looping over all instances and giving out one statement after another or in the iteration process in a while statement: i = i + 1 doing the same. The have got the same procedure as the Kochsche Curve is growing or building recrusevly on itself.

Where the first programmers( Alan Turning, Konrad Zuse) also philisophers ?

[image: Kochsche Curve]

Comment: Welcome to philosophy.se! Honestly I don't get your question. So you can construct the Kochsche Curve geometrically and algorithmically. And that made you wonder, if Zuse and Turing were philosophers? Or are you curious about the similarity of recursion in maths and recursion in programming? Honestly: I don't really get it!

Comment: What Einer said, but also (most simply), you seem to be asking two different questions (one in the title, and one as the last sentence of your body)... can you elaborate on how those two questions should be in the same post (or ask them separately)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ada Lovelace, daughter of the poet Lord Byron is generally recognised as the 'first' programmer.

There is some overlap between the category of philosophy and programming, but it is not large.

Answer (score 0):

These are Mandelbrot Sets. Go to this website to generate your own - http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.html

"THE MANDELBROT SET IS the most complex object in mathematics, its admirers like to say." from 'Chaos: The Making of a New Science' by James Gleik - very good reading

Comment: These are *fractals*, but they are not much more straightforward than the Julia sets of which the Mandelbrot set is the most obvious example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean the [Koch curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) (-sche is a German suffix meaning -ess or -ical?), which according to wikipedia was the work of a Swedish mathematician.

The first programmers were generally mathematicians, or at least formally trained in math at a high level, since the first computers were exclusively for solving math problems; Konrad Zuse was an engineer.  The concept of the **programming loop** and particularly the nesting of loops (which could be used in producing fractals) is credited to [Ada Lovelace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace), also a mathematician, but the daughter of a poet.

Alan Turing appears to have been a bit of a (math-centric) polymath and the concept of the [Turing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) might be considered philosophy, although I do not think it has actually been used or applied  to anything outside of mathematics and computing.

Answer (score -1):

Alan Turing published in philosophy journals, so yes amongst other things should be considered as a philosopher.

Comment: @Rich, can you say more? What was published? What areas did Turing write about?